# Is there any way to reset my Apple ID as all number?

Tags: apple-id, password

I used to have a backup Apple ID that I registered back in 2012 when Apple still allowed you to have a 6-character all number password.

I accidentally enabled two-factor authentication when using this ID to log onto Apple Store. I don’t want the security upgrade. So I immediately tried to disable it following the instructions from the confirmation email. It turns out I have to reset my old password and get a new one following their latest requirement (at least 8 characters with upper and lowercase letters). I want my 6-character all number password back and also have two factor authentication disabled.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: No. And honestly, a 6 digit number is so easy to brute-force that it doesn‘t provide any security at all nowadays.

Comment: I'll take this moment to soap box a second... 6 digit passwords are very weak.   Even "at least 8 characters with upper and lowercase letters" are poor passwords.   Please consider using long pass phrases for your accounts.  The longer a password is, the better.  Using "H@ck3r01" looks secure, but it's not.  Using "NoOneGonnaGuessThisPassword" might seem bad, but it's VERY strong.   Special characters and silly things aren't worth it.   Longer passwords are better.   You can test password strength here:  https://www.passwordmonster.com  if you are curious.

Comment: Obligatory [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/936/) cartoon

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot set a password that doesn't meet the security requirements.